# I can't open Trash and mounted volumes with desktop icons on Gnome after installing Unity

Tags: unity, gnome, icons, trash

Please, nothing happen now when I double click on these icons on Gnome desktop after installing Unity. How can I restore this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to click on the launcher item that looks like a filing cabinet and access mounted volumes and Trash folder from there.

Comment: Yes, but how to re-enable the desktop icons ? May be I have just to set the default application for Nautilus link to Nautilus, but how to do it ?

Comment: Right click on your desktop icon and select properties. This will give you information the old icons worked with.

Comment: No, I don't have any useful information. Thanks.